# Pairwise disjoint proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let the positive real numbers be defined as $\{x\in\Bbb R: x>0\}$. For $x\in\Bbb R^+$ let

$$A_{x}=\{u \in\Bbb R^+: u/x  \in\Bbb Q\}\;.$$

(a) Prove that $\bigcup_{x\in\Bbb R^+}A_x=\Bbb R^+$.

(b) Prove that $\{A_{x}:x \in\Bbb R^+\}$ is pairwise disjoint.

I believe that for part a I need to show subset in both directions and that for part b to show that if the intersection $A_{x}$ and some arbitrary set isn't equal to the empty set then they are equal. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to use mathjax to do the formatting. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for example.

Comment: For (a), note that $x \in A_x$. One direction is immediate from the definition. For (b), show that if $A_x$ and $A_y$ intersect, then they are the same.

Answer (score 3):

HINTS:

For (a) it’s easy to verify that $A_x\subseteq\Bbb R^+$ for each $x\in\Bbb R^+$. For the opposite inclusion remember that $1\in\Bbb Q$, so $x\in\ldots\;$?

You’ve the right general idea for (b). As a preliminary step, though, I’d show that if $x\in A_y$, then $A_x\subseteq A_y$. Then go on and suppose that $z\in A_x\cap A_y$. That tells you that $\frac{z}x,\frac{z}y\in\Bbb Q$. What can you then infer about $\frac{x}y$ and $\frac{y}x$?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18285/discussion-on-answer-by-brian-m-scott-pairwise-disjoint-proof).

Comment: @Wesley: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Ok, excellent. However, for the last part, if x is an element of A_y, then A_x is a subset of A_y, why wouldn't we let y be an element of A_x and show that y is also in A_y?

Comment: @Wesley: You want to show that $A_x=A_y$, and the easiest way to do that is to show that $A_x\subseteq A_y$ and $A_y\subseteq A_x$. (The argument is the same for both.) To do that you must show that if $z\in A_x$, then $z\in A_y$. So write out what it means for $z$ to belong to $A_x$ and what it means for $z$ to belong to $A_y$, and see if you can deduce the latter from the former. It’s the same sort of argument that you’ve been using.

Comment: I understand all of that I was just thrown off by how if x is an element of A_y that from there you can show that A_x is a subset of A_y. I thought via the definition of subset to be a subset that for all x an element of A_x implies x an element of A_y. Or is that irrelevant for what we're doing?

Comment: @Wesley: You’re quite right that in order to show that $A_x\subseteq A_y$, we must show that every element of $A_x$ is an element of $A_y$. That’s the one thing that remains to be done, in fact. The point is that once we know that $x\in A_y$, it’s possible, using the definitions of $A_x$ and $A_y$, to show that every member of $A_x$ is in $A_y$. In general just knowing that $x\in A_y$ of course is not enough, but in this particular setting it gives us just enough extra information to make it possible to prove that in fact every member of $A_x$ is in $A_y$.

Comment: Ah, excellent. So, if we let x be an element of A_y. That is, x is an element of R^+ and x/y is an element of Q. For x to be a an element of A_x, x must be an element of R^+ and x/x must be an element of Q. So, x/x is equal to 1, therefore x/x is an element of Q. Now, all that we need to show is that x is an element of R^+, correct? So, since x is an element of A_y, it is known that x is an element of R^+, yes?

Comment: @Wesley: Back up. You want to start with an arbitrary $z\in A_x$ and show that it’s in $A_y$. You already showed that $x\in A_y$, so you know that $\frac{x}y\in\Bbb Q$. The hypothesis that $z\in A_x$ tells you that $\frac{z}x\in\Bbb Q$. You want to show that $z\in A_y$, i.e., that $\frac{z}y\in\Bbb Q$. One simple observation does it at this point; can you see what it is?

Comment: Ah yes, (x/y)*(z/x) is also a rational number, so (z/y) is likewise rational. Would you feel it necessary to prove those properties of rational numbers on the side or no?

Comment: @Wesley: No, it’s assumed that you know that the rationals are closed under multiplication.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Thank you very much for your time, Brian. I wish i could return the favor.

Comment: @Wesley: You’re welcome (and don’t worry about it: that’s what I’m here for).